# no rendering in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried many ways but I can't solve my problem.
in android studio I don't have rendering and preview . ( under image )

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CRwV.png)

and this is my actvity_main codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

I remove `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` and solve my problem but not complete , because I can't add widgets on my phone . ( like under image )

[custom view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyqXj.png)

I can't add button or any thing on my device screen , I tried change theme , I tried change API level ( from 22 to 21 ) , I tried many times build and rebuild and clean project and Invalidates caches / restart but my problem was not solwed 
please help me ):

and this is my content_main.xml code : ( I replace content code on activity main codes , but when I run my app I see only a white page !!) :

code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="barnamenevis.fdsoft.farzam.test.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your `content_main.xml`, too?

Comment: @BobMalooga I add.

Comment: As I suspected. You miss the `<merge />` tag.

Comment: @BobMalooga what ? I don't understand ! sorry

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: @BobMalooga I can't resolve my problem , and I have another question , I have another eror : "Parse exception while reading distributions.json: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $" it's related to my rendering problem ?

Comment: Nope. This errror is related to JSON. Do you need to use JSON in your project? If not, get rid of any reference to that.

Comment: @BobMalooga I did not get content of that link , can you write solution type answer ?

Comment: Move the `<RelativeLayout />` in the incude**r** layout. The `<include />` tag must be contained inside it. Then replace the `<RelativeLayout />` tag in the include**d** layout with the `<merge />` tag. And you should be golden.

Comment: @BobMalooga I'm sorry I tried it but not working , can you type code ? and take screen shot or photo of code and give me ? please , I need this

Comment: My computer is busy rendering 360 frames of a 3D animation - I can't open my IDE, since it's very heavy.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the api 23,[set the api version to 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7XMI.png)